# USB device not recognized w/ extension on one computer, not another

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

fairly odd problem:

We upgraded computers at our site, from computers with USB2.0 WIN7, to USB3.0 WIN8.1.

One particular USB device will not function with an extension cable, but will without it, while the old computer worked with the extension. (We've eliminated the extension being the problem)

What could be done?

We've updated chipset drivers and installed latest drivers for Windows and the device we're trying to use.

Let me know if you need any additional information.